# How to compare varchar parameters in a natively compiled stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, in-memory-database, oltp

I am migrating some tables and stored procedures to in-memory optimized tables and natively compiled stored procedures. I'm getting stuck on string comparison.

> Comparison, sorting, and manipulation of character strings that do not
>   use a *_BIN2 collation is not supported with natively compiled stored
>   procedures.

```
CREATE TABLE [User].[FingerPrints]
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 10000),
    FingerPrint VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
    SecretKey VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    BranchId int NOT NULL,
    SteadySign bit NOT NULL,
    CreatedOn datetime NOT NULL,
    ModifiedOn datetime NOT NULL
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [User].[GetFingerPrint]
    @Id int,
    @SecretKey VARCHAR(512)
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
(
 TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'us_english'
)

SELECT [Id]
      ,[FingerPrint]
      ,[SecretKey]
      ,[BranchId]
      ,[SteadySign]
      ,[CreatedOn]
      ,[ModifiedOn]
  FROM [User].[FingerPrints]
  WHERE [Id] = @Id AND [SecretKey] = @SecretKey

END
GO
```

Comment: So can you change SecretKey to use a BIN2 collation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the collation of the `@SecretKey` parameter appears to work for me, in a copy of AdventureWorks2014:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [User].[GetFingerPrint]
    @Id int,
    @SecretKey VARCHAR(512) 
    WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
(
 TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'us_english'
)

SELECT [Id]
      ,[FingerPrint]
      ,[SecretKey]
      ,[BranchId]
      ,[SteadySign]
      ,[CreatedOn]
      ,[ModifiedOn]
  FROM [User].[FingerPrints]
  WHERE [Id] = @Id AND [SecretKey] = @SecretKey COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN2

END
GO
```

Comment: Be sure that this won't break callers expecting a different collation